# problem with encryption & decryption connectionStrings

Tags: c#, asp.net, cmd

I used the following command to encrypt my connection string but an error ocurred

> "The connection name
>   'DatabaseConnectionString1' was not
>   found in the applications
>   configuration or the connection string
>   is empty"

How can I encrypt it while keeping the application working?

The command used was

```
aspnet_regiis -pef "connectionStrings" "C:\Users\ANAS\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\WebSites\WebSite7"
```

What if I move the encrypted application to another computer? Will it work?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I encrypt it while keeping the
>   application working?

You can't. If you change your web.config your application is initialized.

> What if I move the encrypted
>   application to another computer? Will
>   it work?

It will not work. You can only encrypt config sections on the same machine you decrypted it before. That's the reason why this is secure: You can't take a config file away and decrypt it on another machine.

Comment: Could i use Assymetric key so that i can encrypt it and decrypt it  on another machine

Comment: I think you can follow this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yxw286t2(v=vs.80).aspx and use RSA key containers to pool keys for multiple servers, but I have no experience with this procedure.